# Redirect root to subdirectory apache

Tags: wordpress, apache, redirect

I have an apache server with a WordPress website set up at root and a WordPress website in a subdirectory. I would like for the website in the subdirectory to be the default website. For example, when someone goes to www.example.com I would like for them to see the website that is actually located at www.example.com/newsite but the URL needs to stay the same, www.example.com.

Is doing something like that possible with say a 301 redirect or some other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this out, you just need some htaccess changes:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

Answer (score 0):

You can simply move/copy the files to the root folder in case you are having root access.

> cp -pR /path/to/rootfolder/subdirectory(wordpress)/* /path/to/rootfolder/

Thats it. Don't complicate by putting redirects.

In case you are having a control panel like cPanel, Its easy to put redirects. But as far as I concern moving/copying the files are more reliable.